# how to replace a line based on variable match using sed

Tags: sed

Is it possible to use sed to replace some text based on the matching of a condition at the beginning of the text...  For example, for the following file, I only want to replace the word 'guest' to 'unwanted-guest' only for the line that begins with the pattern '
541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001' which is a variable.

```
541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:x:1000:1000:OpenShift guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:x:1001:1001:OpenShift guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
```

Comment: Try with sed -i 's/\\(^541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001.*\\)guest/\1unwanted-guest/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '/^541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001/ s/guest/unwanted-guest/'
```

We have placed a condition in front of the usual `sed` substitute command.  The condition is:

```
/^541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001/
```

This condition limits `sed` to considering only lines that start with `541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001`  (The caret `^` means must-be-at-the-beginning-of-a-line).  The substitute command is:

```
s/guest/unwanted-guest/
```

This replaces the first occurrence of `guest` on the line with `unwanted-guest`.

#### Example

Applying this command to your sample input (placed in a file named `file`):

```
$ sed '/^541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001/ s/guest/unwanted-guest/' file
541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:x:1000:1000:OpenShift unwanted-guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:x:1001:1001:OpenShift guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
```

#### Using with a variable

```
$ id=541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001
$ sed "/^$id/ s/guest/unwanted-guest/" file
541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:x:1000:1000:OpenShift unwanted-guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:x:1001:1001:OpenShift guest:/var/lib/openshift/541ce468c3b4f843ec000029:/usr/bin/oo-trap-user
```

Comment: looks good...but how can I do this if 541ce0a0c3b4f843ec000001 is a variable